# Meteor - How do I use tarang:ssl correctly?

Tags: ssl, meteor, https, package

For some client feature, I need to implement HTTPS on my Meteor website.

I installed Tarang:ssl package into Meteor and I have 3 files:

```
private/ca.pem
private/cert.pem
private/key.pem
```

My current Meteor configuration is set as follow:

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
    SSLProxy({
       port: 443,
       ssl : {
            key: Assets.getText("key.pem"),
            cert: Assets.getText("cert.pem"),
            ca: Assets.getText("ca.pem")
       }
    });
    ....
}
```

My Meteor server is launched as follow:

```
sudo meteor run --port 80 --allow-superuser
```

Do I made something wrong or do I forgot something?

Answer (score 1):

I set my local HTTPS port to `3100` to bypass `443` sudo requirements. I run meteor with `--port 3100` and that works for me. Also, I only set `key` and `cert` in `SSLProxy({})`.